# delete all duplicate rows in mySQL 5.7.9

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
 select id,channel,post from posts limit 10
+------+------------+-------+
| id   | channel    | post  |
+------+------------+-------+
| 1433 | channel2   | 19353 |
| 1434 | channel2   | 19353 |
| 1435 | channel2   | 19354 |
| 1436 | channel2   | 19354 |
| 1437 | channel2   | 19356 |
| 1438 | channel2   | 19357 |
| 1439 | channel2   | 19358 |
| 1440 | channel2   | 19359 |
| 1441 | channel2   | 19360 |
| 1634 | channel2   | 19360 |
+------+------------+-------+
```

in that table `id` is a `primary key` , now in that table i have a duplicate post for a channel, i try to add a `unique key` to table and remove all duplicate row with this query

```
ALTER ignore TABLE `posts` ADD UNIQUE key `unique_index` (`channel`, `post`);
```

but in `mysql 5.7.9` we can not do that !

so i want to know how can i delete duplicate row and add a unique key for `channel`, `post`

---

**Solution**

```
    DELETE FROM posts
WHERE ID Not in (SELECT* 
                 FROM (SELECT MIN(ID)
                       FROM posts 
                       GROUP BY channel, Post) B
                )
```

Comment: i assume you want to keep the records with the minimal id?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Realy that is not important right now so not different  !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the same table in a subquery within a delete.
So you need to use a extra delivered table to overcome that problem.

```
DELETE FROM
 posts 
WHERE
 posts.id NOT IN (  
  SELECT 
   id
  FROM (    
    SELECT 
      MIN(id) AS id
    FROM
      posts 
    GROUP BY
      posts.channel
    , posts.post
  ) 
   AS 
    posts_id    
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of the data in terms of sets.

You want a sub set of the records by channel post with the min ID for a channel and post (the records to keep) Then you want to delete from posts where an ID from all your posts is not in the sub set (records to keep) you created.

```
DELETE FROM posts
WHERE ID Not in (SELECT* 
                 FROM (SELECT MIN(ID)
                       FROM posts 
                       GROUP BY channel, Post) B
                )
```

Thus you keep all the channel/posts with their min(ID).  you could use max(ID) or we could get much fancier; but as you don't have a preference...

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74de2a/1/0)

Comment: however i do this : `DELETE FROM posts WHERE id in (SELECT minid from (select min(id) as minid from posts GROUP BY channel, post HAVING COUNT(*)>1) x) `  and this is work !

Comment: Just nested a subquery around it.

Comment: YES ! anyway thank you ! i do that with your help :)